# Selenium IDE: controlKeyDown and the likes not working

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm still studying for my computer science degree and have mostly focused on the mathematics side of things for now.  However, in my current job I am working with Selenium IDE (specifically because it doesn't require coding knowledge) and I'm having a bit of trouble:

I need to test a Shift + click as well as a cherry-pick (Control + click) command on the web-based software we are creating, but it's not working.  Manually pressing control and then clicking different elements on the screen works fine, however.

Like I said, I'm using Selenium IDE 2.9.1, and I'm using it on Firefox 50.0.2 on a Windows 10 install.  My commands on that section are as follows:

[Screenshot of the IDE command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igU48.jpg)

The idea, obviously, being to select the object named Field1, depressing the Ctrl key, selecting the object named Field2 and then releasing the Ctrl key.  This should, theoretically anyway (and does work when done manually outside of the IDE), select Field1 and then cherry-pick Field2 from the list as well.

This, however, is not the case, and it doesn't work.

Can anyone, please, advise me on how to proceed here?  Should the commands be structured differently?  Am I using the incorrect commands?  Is there something else I can try?

As a PS:  The same issue persists with the shiftKeyDown command as well.

I have searched for this issue online and found no help that actually works for me yet, hence this post.

I am looking forward to your replies, in the hope that I can find success...  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the solution.

When compiling the tests I test them by running through them step by step to ensure that everything is working like it should, before saving it to a test suite and letting it run on it's own.  Now, this involves me double-clicking every command in the Table one by one, in sequence, and keeping and eye on the screen to ensure that it executes and behaves exactly like I want it to.  Simple, understandable, logical, correct?

Well, it seems like the controlKeyDown and controlKeyUp commands DO NOT WORK in this way.

I built a bare-minimum test case using only the 4 commands:  click the element, controlKeyDown, click the next element, controlKeyUp.  I ran through the test a hundred times with no success, but then I started thinking - what if the controlKeyDown command is never released?  That would cause issues outside of the test (on the rest of the environment, obviously), since the Ctrl key would be permanently depressed.  So I figured that the Selenium IDE either 1. Releases the key in a short amount of time automatically (faster than I can execute the command to click the next element manually) or 2. It simple ignores the controlKeyDown command if it's not run in a complete test case/suite.

So I took the 4-line test case, built up a test screen with test grid elements and ran the test case - and it works.  Perfectly, actually.

So, in case anyone has similar issues in the future, try to RUN the test case instead of clicking through it or executing commands manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is a Selenium IDE original command problem. 
When you tried to simulate pressing Ctrl key and used "controlKeyDown/Up" command, it just changed the boolean value and did not fired a real key down/up event. Also Shift and Alt key could not work. 
Maybe you should try to add a **"keyDown/Up" command** after "controlKeyDown/Up" command and the target could be //body . 
And, if you need, please try to use the tool, SideeX, the extended version of Selenium IDE. Maybe this problem will be solve in the future and make the test case flexible. Here is the link to [SideeX](http://sideex.org) and there are more details about the tool.

Comment: Thanks for the answer bud, much appreciated.  I have tried this (in all kinds of combinations), but it doesn't seem to work either.  If you are right (and I assume that you might be), and it's a Selenium IDE original command problem, then I am at a loss at what to do.

The way I see it, if Selenium only changes the backend boolean value and there is no way of forcing it to be pulled through to the active screen, I must either use a different command of figure out a different way to select multiple elements in a list.

Anyone have any ideas?